# How to write MySQL Query IF ELSEIF ELSE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write MySQL query if else for this table,

table name: users

```
user_id | username | password | status
1  | john  | 1 | 1
2  | jessi | 2 | 0
3  | mark  | 1 | 2
```

status: 1 - enable, 0 - disable, 2 - deleted

I wrote SQL to get status data :

```
SELECT username, user_id, IF( STATUS =1,  'Enable',  'Disable' ) AS user_status
FROM `users`
```

**how to write MySQL if elseif else statement for get all three status**

Comment: That logic is most appropriately placed in [a `CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski could you please explain how to write case for this

Comment: See answers below, something like... `CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 'Enable' WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN 'Disable' WHEN STATUS = 2 THEN 'Deleted' ELSE 'Unknown Status' END`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CASE statment for that. Like this:

```
SELECT 
   username, 
   user_id, 
   (CASE STATUS
     WHEN 1 
     THEN 'Enable'
     WHEN 0 
     THEN 'Disable'
     WHEN 2
     THEN 'Deleted'
     ELSE 'Unknowed' 
   END) AS user_status 
FROM  
   `users`
```

Reference:

- [13.6.5.1 CASE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case.html)

Comment: The OP has 3 states _1 - enalbe, 0 - disalbe, 2 - deleted_

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Update the answer. With the cases. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested IFs:

```
SELECT username, user_id, IF( `status`=1,  'Enable',  IF(`status`=2, 'Deleted', 'Disabled') ) AS user_status FROM  `users`
```